# openssl verify - error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, verify

i created a PEM certificate from a PFX certificate and wanted to verify it.
However i ran into this issue, try to find some answers, but i didnt and therefore i dont know how to fix it. 
could you please advice?
thank you very much.

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg

C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl
OpenSSL> verify C:\mycert.pem
C:\mycert.pem: C = CZ, ST = Sprava zakladnich registru, L = "Obec=Praha,Ulice=Na Vapence,PSC=13000", O = 72054506, OU = 4333, CN = tstcawilly.szr.local
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
error in verify
OpenSSL>
OpenSSL> verify -CAfile C:\mycert.pem C:\mycert.pem
C:\mycert.pem: C = CZ, ST = Sprava zakladnich registru, L = "Obec=Praha,Ulice=Na Vapence,PSC=13000", O = 72054506, OU = 4333, CN = tstcawilly.szr.local
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
error in verify
OpenSSL>
```

Comment: Same problem here with a fresh certificate issued to us and installed on a tomcat server.

Answer (score 32):

> OpenSSL> verify -CAfile C:\mycert.pem C:\mycert.pem

Close. You need to add the CA's root certificate with `-CAfile`; and not your end entity certificate. Something like:

```
openssl verify -CAfile C:\ca-cert.pem C:\mycert.pem
```

Also, if there is an intermediate certificate, then it needs to be added to `mycert.pem`. So `mycert.pem` will actually have two (or more) certificates (rather than one).

Adding all required certificates to `mycert.pem` in an effort to build a valid chain solves the ["which directory"](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/pkitutorial.pdf) problem. Its a well known problem in PKI. Essentially, a client (like me) does not know where to go to get missing intermediate certificates.

Comment: In the case of a self-signed certificate, isn't the self-signed cert both the CA cert and the entity cert?

Comment: @WilburWhateley - No. Basic Constraints and `CA:FALSE` must be set. `CA:TRUE` cannot be set. If the CA attribute were true, the end entity certificates could mint other certificates.

Comment: So impossible with self-signed?  Not clear. Because there is only one cert in this case, right?  So a self-signed cannot be a CA, and without a CA, you can't verify... Is there something I'm missing, or is this generally a bad design for SSL.

Comment: @WilburWhateley I'm rather new to using openssl but from what I've gathered openssl trusts no CA by default, you have to specify to it what CA(s) to trust. Additionally, you can create a CA yourself with openssl (`CA:TRUE`). Therefore to get a self-signed certificate to verify you need to first create your CA's certificate & key, then create your "self-signed" certificate by signing it with that newly created CA. At that point you can now verify your self-signed certificate, using your own CA. At least that's what I've gathered the past 48 hours or so, and have it working locally.

Answer (score 5):

Another case is `pathlen` can only be set when `CA:TRUE` in `basicConstraints`.

Example:

```
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE,pathlen:10 # Okay
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE,pathlen:10 # Invalid!
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had been beating my head against a wall for about an hour because I had set CA:FALSE, pathlen:0 on my leaf certificates ... the cert created OK, but openssl verify failed to validate it. 

Making the simple change to just be CA:FALSE resulted in validate-able certificates

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems using the openssl verify command properly. So I also got the error:
"error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate"

Here is a short explanation how to use the openssl verify command correctly if you have a certificate chain with multiple intermediate certificates (more than 2 certificates).

Lets imagine we have following certificate chain:
my_root_ca.crt > my_intermediate_ca1.crt > my_intermediate_ca2.crt > leaf_cert.crt

```
openssl verify -CAfile my_root_ca.crt -untrusted all_my_intermediate_ca.crt leaf_cert.crt
```

**my_root_ca.crt**: This is the root certificate (self-signed)

**all_my_intermediate_ca.crt**: This file must include both intermediate certificates (my_intermediate_ca1.crt & my_intermediate_ca2.crt)

**leaf_cert.crt**: This is the actual certificate that gets verified.

So this would also work if you have more than two intermediate certificates. But you must include them all in one file.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered two potential issues you might face.

**Potential issue 1.**
The intermediate certificates might give you an issue.

When verifying our new QSeal certificate (in PEM format) against multiple intermediate certificates, I used option -untrusted for each intermediate certificate.
Here follows an example on MacOS / Linux.

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ./quovadis_root_ca1g3.pem -untrusted ./quovadis_quovadisenterprisetrustca1g3.pem -untrusted ./quovadis_quovadiseuissuingcertificationauthorityg4.pem ./qseal_new.crt
```

Output is now

```
./qseal_new.crt: OK
```

**Potential issue 2.**
I get keeping this issue when using LibreSSL, even when fixing the intermediate certificate issue. Switching to OpenSSL solved it. I am aware that you use Windows, but others might encounter this issue when using an OpenSSL alternative.